# Why doesn't nautilus search find anything outside of my home folder?

Tags: nautilus, search

I installed nginx using apt-get.  There are now many folders and files with "nginx" in their name.  Using the file browser (nautilus) i search for "nginx" with "All Files" selected.

It will not find anything outside of my home folder. I have restarted and also tried the command updatedb, but it still cant find anything outside my home folder.

How do I change this?  It feels like search is broken.

Comment: I think this is a "feature" of nautilus. I also tried searching for bash just now. Once I clicked Computer, and then done search, it worked. So , the search in nautilus basically descends down the folders. If you may understand that better it is doing similar job as `find . -name "*nginx*"`

Comment: Why are you doing this? There may be an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you navigate the nautilus to the parent directory of `/home`.

For example File System that you can search all of the file in your machine.

To perform search just simply press Ctrl+F.

Please note that: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME 3 Classic.

[Source](http://unix.findincity.net/view/63539508700411522941466/how-to-make-nautilus-search-useful-outside-of-home)

Answer (score 1):

The search isn't broken. But for a systemwide search it's better to use more powerful tools like `locate` or `find` in a terminal.

---

For a systemwide search with Nautilus you have to change the location to `/`. Open the location bar with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and enter `/` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that start the search again with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
Additionally check the search settings in your system settings. There you can exclude or include folders.

---

For an efficient system-wide search using the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
find / -type d -iname "*nginx*"
```

The command starts a search in the root of your file system an searches all folders with `nginx` in the name.

```
locate fstab
```

Search for `fstab`, a file in `/etc`.

If you still do not find a folder or file, then start the search with `sudo`

```
sudo find / -iname "*nginx*"
```

Read the man pages for these commands

```
man find
man locate
```

Comment: (Thank you for the working command line answer.) Your suggestion about using ctr+l and entering /  (i beleive is no different than simply navigating to root by clicking "Computer") does not work

Comment: @user3731825 That's true, but I'm faster with the keyboard than with the mouse.

Comment: So the question remains unanswered.  Can you explain how this does not make nautilus search broken?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Start a search with `sudo find ...`

Comment: It works when I avoid clicking "All Files".   So nautilus search is not broken, just the "All Files" button.

Comment: -update-  not sure how I was able to make it work earlier.  No matter what I try now, the / always becomes "Home" and the "All Files" button active.  Nautilus search (on my fresh install of 14.04)  is broken.  Nemo on the other hand, works great. (suggested by Tim)

Answer (score 1):

It searches wherever you have selected, the current directory. There are also 2 searches.

This is the first:

[image]

Type and it will search the current location, and select the folder with that name. If there are multiple with the same starting with the current search, it will chose the first by current sorting (alphabetically by default).

Then there is the real search, to search the folder and all files / folders in it:

[image]

To access this, click the search icon, in the top bar.

Here, you are searching "Home" by default. You want to search a different folder, so there are 2 ways to get that:

- If you want to search from the root directory, all the computer (`/`) click All Files.
- If you want to search a certain folder, navigate there and then use the search tool.

Your question sounds like you want to search everywhere (although I'm not sure why). So click the All Files at the top, or click Computer at the side, and then do your search.

---

As an alternative, install `nemo`:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

It is based on the same code as nautilus, but may work when nautilus doesn't.

Comment: As I have pointed out in my question, this does not work.

Comment: @user3731825 did you try my other solution? Click computer then search? Are you sure there is a file with that name?

Comment: You are not sure why someone would want to search everywhere?  I find that very strange.  Doesn't my question imply that I'm looking for folders associated with nginx?

Comment: @user3731825 yes, it does make it clear *what* you're doing. I'm confused why you need to search for it - there may be a way to achieve what you're doing without searching with Nautilus.

Comment: Yes I am sure that I am searching from root and clicking on the "All Files" button.  This does not change anything.

Comment: @user3731825 okay. I can't solve this direct issue, but I can offer to help solve your overall problem - why do you need to find `nginx` folders?

Comment: My problem is that nautilus search is broken.  It would be very useful if it was not.  The nginx search is really just an example.  Why is there a button that says "All Files" if it doesn't search all the files or at least the ones it has access to?   I am often looking for where certain things are in my computer and it would be just swell if I could search for them from the file browser.  But its broken.

Comment: I got it working by NOT clicking "All Files".

Comment: @user3731825 for most people it *does* search all files. If you install `nemo` does the search work in that?

Answer (score 0):

To make nautilus search all files, simply avoid clicking "All Files".
So nautilus search does indeed work, its the "All Files" button that does not.
-update- I can not reproduce this. The / always becomes "Home" and the "All Files" button active.  I am using Nemo instead of Nautilus now. (suggested by Tim)

Comment: All files works for me, and searches everywhere: http://imgur.com/YNb9RTR (albeit slowly)

Comment: doesn't for me, and it seems tricky to even get the / option.  it tends to switch to Home  http://imgur.com/UVgq3Yz

Comment: You sure there is a file with that name?

Comment: yes, for example the file nsswitch.conf is in the /etc directory  http://imgur.com/T5feI9E  I now click on "Computer"  http://imgur.com/TiJMutw (notice the / next to "All Files")  after entering "nsswitch.conf" the / is now "Home" http://imgur.com/HgzjdJ2 and there is no way to search for the file.   Even following A.B.'s suggestion of using control+l and control+f is no help.  I don't know how I made it work earlier.  It is, without a doubt, broken.  Nemo is working great btw. thank you.

Comment: okay, no more suggestions I'm afraid. Glad nemo works!